# Does Windows 10 have "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)" folders?

Tags: windows-10

I have not installed Windows 10 yet, but I am curious if Microsoft has finally gotten rid of folders with spaces in their names, and if they have gotten rid of the split between x86 and 64-bit folders.

Do these two separate folders still exist in Windows 10?

Comment: Why would they get rid of spaces in folder names? They're just normal unless you're still using DOS.

Comment: Doing so would break thousands of programs and scripts, so Microsoft can't do this until they no longer support 32bit application (like in some server versions) but on the desktop that will not happen for quite some time.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the 64-bit Windows 10 still has **both** folders to allow installation of the 32 and 64 bit version of the same application side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

- The "Program Files (x86)" directory is for 32-bit applications
- The "Program Files" directory is where the 64-bit applications go

The 32-bit version of Windows 10 only has "Program Files," which is for 32-bit applications.

Comment: This pretty much duplicates an answer already given. Make sure that what you're posting is unique and adds to the conversation before posting.